# Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbz;

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting these frustrating errors when attempting a gradle release build of a signed APK in Android Studio. One of the 7 errors is Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbz;

Here is the gradle Console Output:

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72500Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCustomtabs2500Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestTestingSupportLib01Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTestUiautomatorUiautomatorV18212Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTransition2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidVolleyVolley100Library
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidAccountKitSdk4180Library
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidAudienceNetworkSdk4180Library
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk4180Library
:app:prepareComGithubCoyarzun89Fabtransitionactivity020Library
:app:prepareComGithubOzodrukhCircularReveal131Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidExoplayerExoplayerR158Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds840Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerV4Impl1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAppindexing1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid1001Library
:app:prepareComGoogleMapsAndroidAndroidMapsUtils04Library
:app:prepareNetSteamcraftedLoadToast1010Library
:app:prepareNetYslibraryKeyboardvisibilityeventKeyboardvisibilityevent101Library
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseGoogleServices
Parsing json file: C:\Users\antho\AndroidStudioProjects\suRRo\app\google-services.json
:app:generateReleaseResources
:app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileRelease
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease

Running dex as a separate process.

To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has 1024 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to at least 4608 MB (based on the dexOptions.javaMaxHeapSize = 4g).
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html


AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzbz;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzai;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzai$zza;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzai$zzb;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzai$zzc;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzai$zzd;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzai$zze;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzai$zzf;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzai$zzg;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error converting bytecode to dex:\nCause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted","sources":[{}],"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:\njava.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:613)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)\n\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)\nCaused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors\n\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:605)\n\t... 4 more\n","tool":"Dex"}

:app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --force-jumbo --num-threads=4 --multi-dex --output C:\Users\antho\AndroidStudioProjects\suRRo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\release\folders\1000\1f\main C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\2d0b91b1c1c87808b2e3340e90ac83a720b15f50\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\a7a058614312b7a634e1cbc699ed60d0ef57f501\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-api\2.5\e7fd981408caba8a0c0fb276413562468d260160\log4j-api-2.5.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\aaf405a541520b4e4077fdefe0fcb1c796c17608\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.4.0\d6a66c7a5f01cf500377bd669507a08cfeba882a\jackson-annotations-2.4.0.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\ac1e5c369d56f1b4ec7890c48bac586070d34243\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\c174b3d25e69025e44814ef345573464589ffd2d\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\b763cf772457e939e914c0794d87762d4c7f0fcd\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\7b0bb18190c5d4348456cc5833551352204457c7\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\65dc799efbb181f4617e9dc488b1bc2d844bd446\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\131c5523d1c6a055766b00aedc2581c6a3a8e49f\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.4.2\ceb72830d95c512b4b300a38f29febc85bdf6e4b\jackson-core-2.4.2.jar C:\Users\antho\AndroidStudioProjects\suRRo\app\libs\httpclient-4.5.1.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\18c93fb35c04381f761571b82bc4a31ca5c1e905\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-annotations\25.0.1\support-annotations-25.0.1.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\afe31b5f75506c2e56edcdf521edecfe36d32b72\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.1\860340562250678d1a344907ac75754e259cdb14\hamcrest-core-1.1.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\27a595fcfbc73f29f29b1fb461cc5f86f5318c8c\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\99ce96694731ff47b104f2e290f67fe10ce90c54\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\fdd1d0c87a40cf863e704483c0ef58a4ff029324\output\jars\libs\internal_impl-25.0.1.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\74fd0bcdbd9ce8252c8b8ff0fef5999144799f9e\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\42c36cf9c2f6d278402c8540ff48575a20db3fb3\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\67fa7bfce85d308be6fc4b9ba769bfd8c677694f\output\jars\libs\internal_impl-25.0.1.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\d5dcb7f8701d53bdda06c0468a25b4b0f3218ba9\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\2258f8b1fc724b8596ba44ccce89a6344d994c23\output\jars\libs\internal_impl-25.0.1.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\fe966e9f5777e76d91fdf25e6ddb8fa5abca49f0\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\3fd480b6609ab4b64ad5e40e4c3c580c0cfe5b28\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\aa969ef2a2206302c350fc9da25b4973fcb78e34\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.parse.bolts\bolts-tasks\1.4.0\d85884acf6810a3bbbecb587f239005cbc846dc4\bolts-tasks-1.4.0.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\fe966e9f5777e76d91fdf25e6ddb8fa5abca49f0\output\jars\libs\internal_impl-25.0.1.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\8cac689fa47637e234d097fb344a648a8a4e8eac\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\95134680f666232e9b56425037167f9940c5579c\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.gson\gson\2.4\695b63d702f505b9b916e02272e3b6381bade7f\gson-2.4.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\c9d985492464b4d6f493c3299fe3cfcd53c9814c\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\2d0b91b1c1c87808b2e3340e90ac83a720b15f50\output\jars\libs\internal_impl-25.0.1.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\fdd1d0c87a40cf863e704483c0ef58a4ff029324\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\67fa7bfce85d308be6fc4b9ba769bfd8c677694f\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\8b395f0464ca19c82b8b12a95c601918c8ededc6\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\f6c8c1a1e59d4c435d1849d2bd756adbc0e948ce\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\af273acbd78dfb7869cd92938b5f0f64aed37737\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\AndroidStudioProjects\suRRo\app\libs\common-lang3.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\a279b16f426a47a725cb11ebbb9f91e21324970a\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\4044de0f4e99590b27abe31e592799a6f6b22909\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.parse.bolts\bolts-applinks\1.4.0\8ad21bf21784dacce5f2043afb97218cc377e835\bolts-applinks-1.4.0.jar C:\Users\antho\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\junit-dep\4.10\64417b3bafdecd366afa514bd5beeae6c1f85ece\junit-dep-4.10.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\a6a746c76b80fb188a449e9dc90808d61464d15a\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\dcedf40f0b285b2c5a5bf8d72b971dd3281f2058\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\41f0bed0c279cdfbeddddfd188f9da5fa63d32aa\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.4.2\8e31266a272ad25ac4c089734d93e8d811652c1f\jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\9e62638a47b2a6ad55f57536070e28935f57d98e\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\b087012239c40414676ceea614da7db4cee81385\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\0e8bce1e98224e469a4886ca72d8386891ef45cd\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\AndroidStudioProjects\suRRo\app\build\intermediates\classes\release C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\4c0fe81be18463201973d15abb1c132c9abf7150\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\AndroidStudioProjects\suRRo\app\libs\httpcore-4.4.3.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\2f9d494d73626bc874dd2faf38cfd1b1219a3755\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\47b157cd79531994adab5447efea8041ed038aee\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\8a6b9a62ff5b629bae4798656cea706b3f90a0bf\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\c9d985492464b4d6f493c3299fe3cfcd53c9814c\output\jars\libs\internal_impl-25.0.1.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\9bff2a736b283147fd0c814e123bcf0f224ab162\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\AndroidStudioProjects\suRRo\app\libs\rabbitmq-client.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\2258f8b1fc724b8596ba44ccce89a6344d994c23\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\ee47fdf395ed82d328d79020b5ca98da7f61abd5\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.nineoldandroids\library\2.4.0\e9b63380f3a242dbdbf103a2355ad7e43bad17cb\library-2.4.0.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\f2b28e73da25dbc4a49a01a3e145300917435d27\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\e1ddaa2ecd6104c4ac36217a4681b182fe69ab20\output\jars\classes.jar C:\Users\antho\.android\build-cache\890602f5504b8a1586620d80ada235b0686b86a8\output\jars\classes.jar}

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 17.147 secs
```

Here is my Gradle File for the App:

```
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services'
}


android {
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        jumboMode = true
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/antho/.android/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            keyAlias ''
            keyPassword ''
            storeFile file('')
            storePassword ''
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mobilereign.suRRoLive"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.1"
        multiDexEnabled = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            renderscriptDebuggable false
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            renderscriptDebuggable true
            zipAlignEnabled false
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'libs/gson-1.7.1.jar'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }

}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/common-lang3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar')
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.5'
    compile files('libs/rabbitmq-client.jar')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.2'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.2'
    compile 'net.steamcrafted:load-toast:1.0.10'
    compile 'com.github.coyarzun89:fabtransitionactivity:0.2.0'
    compile 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'

}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


    Here is my Gradle File for the Project:

    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Basically I am wondering if anyone can tell me what I need to exclude from a particular dependency or dependencies to make this work. I have wasted 2 days on this. I am very frustrated and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I installed the very latest version of Android Studio (2.3) and I changed my Gradle File for the APP to this:

Comment: having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

For the error "already added:..." : it seems You have same dependence/jar included twice.

Check with command line :

```
gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile
```

Then exclude module included twice.

Answer (score -1):

I guess your gradle heap size is too small
First of all:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    jumboMode = true
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

is deprecated

Secondly:
and add

```
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608M
```

in your root project gradle.properties

thirdly:
sync gradle

Comment: First, half of those settings would have nothing to do with what you think the problem is.  Secondly, it isn't a heap size issue-  it has to do with a library being included multiple times.  Also, configureondemans + parallel isn't really supported yet (gradle tells you its an incubating feature).